# How to preserve measurements when manipulating an object

Tags: modeling, modifiers, measurement

I’m making kitchen cabinets for a project of mine and here’s a problem I ran into: The cabinets should have spaces in between them and at the same time the measurements are supposed to be preserved from left to right. How can I do that?
Without spaces

[image]

With spaces (a little bit exaggerated so I can make my point. This is an eyeballed example just to show what I mean)

[image]

In other words - There are 4 squares where the first and last edge are overlapping with the green line:
[image]

I want to resize the squares equaly with equal spaces btween them, but the overlapping to be preserved:

[image]

I know this can be solved by having a little knowledge of algebra and just tipe the number for the array, but I think there should be an easy way to achieve this in blender without having to bother with algebra too much. Using empties in combination with array and snapping is my guess. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you set pivot points to individual origins? or will that not work.

Comment: @A Radish Thanks for responding. The thing is that the left face of the first cabinet should stay on the same spot even when the cabinet is manipulated as well as the right face on the last cabinet. Just like the images show. And when using the Array modifier this is a little tricky.

Comment: @Vladimir is the space added through scaling on one axis?if so move the origins of the side cabinets to the side faces and scale all objs to individual origins

Comment: The idea is too preserve the dimension from left to right and from top and bottom when the object is resized, which results in the spaces. No, the spaces are made with the Array modifier and applied so I can make the drawers.

Comment: You could use driver.

Comment: I'll try that. The cabinets should be the same size by the way. Thanks for the link

Comment: @Vladimir if all you need is to get the dimension right while the spaces and cabinets are equal , just use the array modifier than change the dimension in the 3D view (right side panel)

Comment: I checked the video and I updated teh question (sorry if it was confusing). If we threat the cabinets as one simple cube then the very left of the object should align with the blue line and the very right of it with the right blue line.

Comment: Vlad, do you *need* to use an array, or can you just do it the way @Chebhou and I said?

Comment: It doesn't has to be an array, but the cabinets to be equal, to have equal spaces between them and the very left face (image 1) to be in the same position at the end (image 2). The same goes for the very right face.

Answer (score 2):

after applying the array modifier seperate the object :

- in edit mode hit  <kbd>P</kbd> and select seperate **by loose parts**
- set the origin to geometry for all objects
- for the side objects set the origin to the side faces

[image]

- scale all to induvidual origins

[image]

Comment: Impresive! I'll try it out. One drawback is that the spaces are not equal, but I think I can get around with that somehow. Just in case, I updated the question again. Thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I got it - Just by activating the snapping tool - snap to vertex, the selection can be easily snapped to the vertex of an edge by scaling it.

From this
[image]

To this
[image]